# How to find specific number in csv file row and count?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

How can i find specific **number** in csv file and count them how many they are in column

In a column there are lots of similar value like 20 30 40 30 20 30

So, How can i find number **20** in a column of csv file and count how many **20** is there in a column?

**Note :** I'm using python 3.8 and pandas

Comment: Can you tell us what've you tried already?

Comment: `df['colName'].value_counts()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang this will count the all value...i just need single value like counting number 20 and printing there are 15 number of 20's present in a colunm

Comment: `df['colName'].eq(20).sum()`?

Comment: @SamChats i tried like  `dataframe['colName'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using pandas [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

try this,

```
import pandas as pd


lst=[10,20,30,30,20,20]
df=pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.columns = ['a']


print(df.head())

print(df['a'].value_counts())
```